# Brand new BR-R7070 brakes, piston issue

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

The ceramic pistons on my brand new BR7070 brakes won't depress at all even with quite a lot of force. There is also a subtle grinding noise when trying to depress the pistons. Did I somehow crack the brand new pistons? How much force does it take to depress these?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It's not clear to me what the question is.  Are you asking for diagnotic tips?  Maintenance instructions?  If anyone else has had a similar problem?  Please [edit] the question to be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: If its a brand new caliper, look into warranty before you go too far.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I disassembled the caliper and the ceramic pistons were both shattered. They were either shattered on arrival or this was from trying to put a bleed block in when the pistons were slightly out. This pushed the pistons into a slight angle. Then they shattered when squeezing the brakes.